# Lifting a (Lens) Traversal to Fix

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I've got the following code. As you can see the last function is `undefined`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DeriveFunctor, DeriveTraversable #-}

module Example where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data PathComponent d a = Directions d | Alt [a] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

makePrisms ''PathComponent

newtype Path d a = Path [PathComponent d a] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

directions :: Traversal (Path a p) (Path b p) a b
directions a2fb (Path l) = Path <$> traverse f l where
    f (Directions d) = Directions <$> a2fb d
    f (Alt p) = (pure . Alt) p

directions' :: Traversal (Fix (Path a)) (Fix (Path b)) a b
directions' = undefined
```

What I ultimately want to do is map every `a` to a `b` recursively in the structure. I was hoping I could do this by lifting `directions` but I seem to be held back by a) the fact the function declares `p` in the `s` and `t` positions and also b) the fact that `_Wrapping` is an `Iso'` not a `Iso`. Is there an elegant way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `directions` we need to traverse the `p` with `a2fb` too. Since `p` is a parameter, we can take its traversal as a parameter. In addition, the `f` you've defined is really a traversal of `PathComponent`, that we can pull out as well.

First, the traversal of `PathComponent a p`, which is parameterized by a traversal of `p` (and generalized so the source and target types can vary):

```
data PathComponent d a = Directions d | Alt [a] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

{- Morally

traversePC ::
  Traversal pa pb a b ->
  Traversal (PathComponent a pa) (PathComponent b pb) a b

   But the following type is both simpler (rank 1) and more general.
-}
traversePC ::
  Applicative m =>
  LensLike m pa pb a b ->
  LensLike m (PathComponent a pa) (PathComponent b pb) a b
traversePC _tp f (Directions d) = Directions <$> f d
traversePC  tp f (Alt pas) = Alt <$> (traverse . tp) f pas
```

In the `Directions` case, we transform the `a` to a `b` directly.
In the `Alt` case, we have a list of `pa`, so we compose a traversal of that list (`traverse`) with the parameter traversal (`tp`).

The traversal of `Path` passes `tp` to `traversePC`.

```
newtype Path d a = Path [PathComponent d a] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

{- Same idea about the types.

directions :: Traversal pa pb a b -> Traversal (Path a pa) (Path b pb) a b

-}

directions ::
  Applicative m =>
  LensLike m pa pb a b ->
  LensLike m (Path a pa) (Path b pb) a b
directions tp f (Path l) = Path <$> (traverse . traversePC tp) f l
```

And finally, to traverse `Fix (Path a)`, this unpacks to `h :: Path a (Fix (Path a))`, and we pass down the toplevel traversal for `Fix (Path a)` recursively.

```
directions' :: Traversal (Fix (Path a)) (Fix (Path b)) a b
directions' f (Fix h) = Fix <$> directions directions' f h
```

In fact, there is a general pattern here for any `Fix`. If you have a functor `f` (here `Path a`), and there is a traversal of `f x` parameterized by a traversal of `x`, then you can tie a knot to get a traversal `traverseFix'` of `Fix f`, applying the parameterized traversal to `traverseFix'` itself.

```
{-

traverseFix ::
  (forall x y. Traversal x y a b -> Traversal (f x) (g y) a b) ->
  Traversal (Fix f) (Fix g) a b

-}

traverseFix ::
  Functor m =>
  (forall x y. LensLike m x y a b -> LensLike m (f x) (g y) a b) ->
  LensLike m (Fix f) (Fix g) a b
traverseFix traverseF = traverseFix' where
  traverseFix' f (Fix h) = Fix <$> traverseF traverseFix' f h
```

So we can redefine `directions'` as follows:

```
directions'' :: Traversal (Fix (Path a)) (Fix (Path b)) a b
directions'' = traverseFix directions
```

[Full gist](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/d9cfc12526f8f2dcedc8cabf31fdc615)